# After upgrade to 19.10 screen lock pops up 5-10 minutes after I log in

Tags: upgrade, screen, 19.10, lock-screen

I just upgraded to 19.10 on my desktop, which uses Intel integrated graphics (no separate GPU). Running with two monitors. Between 5 and 10 minutes after logging in, the screens go black and then I'm asked to log in again. This happens only once per session, not every 5-10 minutes. Everything was normal before the upgrade. Suggestions needed!

Comment: Using the xfce desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered in the 19.10 change notes that xfce-screensaver had "replaced" light-locker. But light-locker was still running on my system. I uninstalled it and killed the running process. That has fixed things.